# pgfplots Error: The provided colormap positions are not multiples of the prescribed mesh width h=1.0000000000

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, matlab2tikz

I produced the output of a `surf` with `matlab2tikz` with an individual colormap, which led to the color of every individual pixel being set to a color value, and every `surf` data point being assigned an individual value to that these are read from the colormap.

Now, my matrix is 101x101, resulting into 10200 colormap points. Somewhen, pgfplots starts to complain about colorbar points not being on the mesh, which is simply not true. The error is

```
! Package pgfplots Error: The provided colormap positions are not multiples of 
the prescribed mesh width h=1.0000000000 (found one with H/h = 0.9999/1.0000000
000= 1+-0.0001 which is no integer). The error occured near `rgb(1019pt)=(0.998
332,0.993606,0.989873) (color no 1019) '.

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.435 ]
     
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

From here, the error occurs randomly for several other colors until `pdflatex` concludes that `(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)`. I don't get a MWE going as the error does not occur on small matrices. The colormap around the spot with the error looks like

```
colormap={patchmap}{
[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.683515,0.87866,0.82487);
% snip
rgb(918pt)=(0.378751,0.761814,0.656226); 
rgb(919pt)=(0.962889,0.857741,0.774684); 
rgb(920pt)=(1,1,1); 
rgb(1018pt)=(1,1,1); 
rgb(1019pt)=(0.998332,0.993606,0.989873); 
rgb(1020pt)=(0.562949,0.832435,0.758153);
% snip
},
```

and also in the data matrix are no spurious floats.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to help as it is now - I could be wrong. Can you post a picture of matlab output, the TikZ code without a colormap? Does it compile?

Comment: I updated the question with parts of what the MATLAB figure looks like. If I remove the colormap in MATLAB, it compiles flawlessly

Comment: @MPFelder, please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. Optimally also add an image of the result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

While the problem has not been resolved, there is a feasible workaround at least for me. I simply used `imagesc` and split the colorbar into the two colors I needed my data points to have (see question). Then, I scaled all points into `x in [0,.5[` and the points of different color got a .5 offset to be in `x in [.5,1]`. The result is satisfactory for me and compiles with my preferred tex variant.